# Change the organization icon in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

How do I change the icon/profile image of an organization in Azure Devops (dev.azure.com)?

I know I could change the project icon by clicking/hovering on it:

[image]

But that isn't possible for the organization. I'm the *Organization owner*.

It this really not possible?
I don't really like the pink icon ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2023-06 this is now possible https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/choose-an-image-for-your-organization/

Official docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-organization-image?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 10):

From June 27th, 2023 this is [possible](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/choose-an-image-for-your-organization/)

[image]
[image]

You can find more details in [the original documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-organization-image?view=azure-devops).

Keep in mind that the max size is 2.5MB.

---

**Original reply.**

I'm afraid that this is not possible. Please check this topic on Developer Community - [Can't change organization's icon](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-change-organizations-icon/617963)

> Thank you for your feedback. Azure DevOps currently doesn't support change organization icon now.

And here you have [a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/change-the-project-or-organization-icons/845740)

Comment: Wow... Microsoft needs to up their game

Comment: also it does not seem that they care - report is closed with a URL pointing nowhere - really not cool